# Adição de watermark com c# sem usar System.Drawing.Bitmap no Azure

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure, multiple-file-upload

sou novo no mundo .NET e estou com um problema no envio de imagens para o site. Estou usando uma função para adicionar a watermark na foto assim que enviada mas aparentemente o Azure não aceita mais a utilização do System.Drawing.Bitmap. Tentei encontrar alguma alternativa mas não consegui, alguma sugestão? Segue abaixo o code:

```
private void AdicionarMarcaDagua(HttpPostedFileBase arquivo, string caminhoTemp, string caminhoFotos, string caminhoThumbs, int id)
    {
        string Copyright = "www.vidaideal.com";

        Image imgPhotoTemp = Image.FromFile(caminhoTemp + arquivo.FileName);
        int novaAltura = 600;
        int novaLargura = 800;

        Bitmap novaImagem = new Bitmap(novaLargura, novaAltura);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)novaImagem);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(imgPhotoTemp, 0, 0, novaLargura, novaAltura);
        g.Dispose();

        novaImagem.Save(caminhoTemp + id +"_" + arquivo.FileName);
        imgPhotoTemp.Dispose();

        Image imgPhoto = Image.FromFile(caminhoTemp + id + "_" + arquivo.FileName);
        int phWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int phHeight = imgPhoto.Height;

        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(phWidth, phHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);

        Image imgWatermark = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Layout/") + "\\watermark-color.png");
        int wmWidth = imgWatermark.Width;
        int wmHeight = imgWatermark.Height;

        grPhoto.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto, new Rectangle(0, 0, phWidth, phHeight), 0, 0, phWidth, phHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        int[] sizes = new int[] { 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4 };

        Font crFont = null;
        SizeF crSize = new SizeF();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            crFont = new Font("Verdana", sizes[i], FontStyle.Bold);
            crSize = grPhoto.MeasureString(Copyright, crFont);

            if ((ushort)crSize.Width < (ushort)phWidth)
                break;
        }

        int yPixlesFromBottom = (int)(phHeight * .05);

        float yPosFromBottom = ((phHeight - yPixlesFromBottom) - (crSize.Height / 2));

        float xCenterOfImg = (phWidth / 2);

        StringFormat StrFormat = new StringFormat();
        StrFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        SolidBrush semiTransBrush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(153, 0, 0, 0));

        grPhoto.DrawString(Copyright, crFont, semiTransBrush2, new PointF(xCenterOfImg + 1, yPosFromBottom + 1), StrFormat);

        SolidBrush semiTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(153, 255, 255, 255));

        grPhoto.DrawString(Copyright, crFont, semiTransBrush, new PointF(xCenterOfImg, yPosFromBottom), StrFormat);

        Bitmap bmWatermark = new Bitmap(bmPhoto);
        bmWatermark.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);
        Graphics grWatermark = Graphics.FromImage(bmWatermark);

        ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();

        ColorMap colorMap = new ColorMap();

        colorMap.OldColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);
        colorMap.NewColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

        ColorMap[] remapTable = { colorMap };

        imageAttributes.SetRemapTable(remapTable, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

        float[][] colorMatrixElements = {
            new float[] {1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f},
            new float[] {0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f},
            new float[] {0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f},
            new float[] {0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.3f, 0.0f},
            new float[] {0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}
        };
        ColorMatrix wmColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(colorMatrixElements);

        imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(wmColorMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default,
            ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

        int xPosOfWm = ((phWidth - wmWidth) - 10);
        int yPosOfWm = 10;
        grWatermark.DrawImage(imgWatermark, new Rectangle(xPosOfWm, yPosOfWm, wmWidth, wmHeight), 0, 0, wmWidth, wmHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);

        imgPhoto = bmWatermark;
        grPhoto.Dispose();
        grWatermark.Dispose();

        imgPhoto.Save(caminhoFotos + id + "_" + arquivo.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        imgPhoto.Dispose();
        imgWatermark.Dispose();
        GerarThumb(caminhoFotos, arquivo, caminhoThumbs, id);
    }
```

Tentei encontrar no próprio Azure alguma documentação a respeito mas não consegui encontrar, vi algo sobre utilizar Blob mas a princípio quero evitar o uso deste recurso pois aumenta o custo mensal de operação sem necessidade.

O .NET que está sendo utilizado é o 4.7.1 Full, linguagem C# com MVC 5.

Comment: Fora a parte que não é a forma correta de fazer este código o Azure não determinada nada, o .NET que está usando pode ser. O .NET Core antes da versão 3.0 (que sai ano que vem) não tem o `System.Drawing` então precisa achar outras bibliotecas para uso agora. Tem gente que usa o SkiaSharp, mas não sei se é bom ou te atende, ou até se é um canhão pra matar passarinho.

Comment: Olá Maniero, tudo bem? Cara, como assim não é a forma correta? Eu faço o upload e chamo o método para adicionar a watermark e redimensionar a imagem, esta forma não é correta? Eu estou usando o .NET 4.7.1 e rodando localmente funciona perfeitamente, é quando publico no Azure que dá erro de parâmetro, olhando nas pastas de imagens ele chega a enviar, redimensionar mas para no watermark.

Comment: Tem uma quantidade enorme de erros, você fez funcionar, mas não está certo. Dá uma pesquisada no site que tem informações sobre. Você chama o `Dispose()` manualmente e "não pode", tem coisas que deveria ter o mesmo tratamento e não tem, tem coisas que funciona se tudo estiver certo, mas quebra a aplicação se não estiver. Procura também aqui sobre a diferença entre .NET Framework e .NET Core.

Comment: Maniero, eu adicionei o Dispose para limpar a memória e eu poder excluir os arquivos temporários mas em teoria não é neles o problema pois o método para de rodar no Bitmap do watermark. Quais erros você se refere? Se puder apontar o que está errado eu agradeço pois como disse sou novo no .NET e não consegui identificar erros no código. Agora o que tem a ver a diferença entre .NET e o Core? Não estou usando Core, não entendi seu ponto com relação a isso.

Comment: Acabei de falar quais erros são. E são muitos. Por estar começando acho que está fazendo coisas avançadas demais, seria melhor compreender o básico antes de partir para o avançado. Então você está usado o .NET Framework full no Azure? Você tem certeza disto? Sua pergunta não deixa claro, o que indica que ela deveria ser fechada.

Comment: Desculpe Maniero mas não vi nenhum erro apontado, apenas o uso desnecessário do Dispose e dei uma razão para tal uso. Eu sei que preciso compreender o básico mas neste momento o que preciso é desta informação. Conforme informei na minha primeira interação, estou utilizando .NET 4.7.1 - afirmei, não disse "acho". Realmente não informar na pergunta foi um esquecimento meu e vou editar agora. Partindo da premissa que o runtime indica erros e o código compila, não sei identificar  qual o problema deste código então se puder ser mais específico sobre os vários erros eu agradeço imensamente.

Comment: Só uma pequena correção: faltou o não na útlima frase, o runtime não acusa erros e compila normalmente. Localmente roda sem nenhum problema a aplicação toda.